# ssrs error Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I open a report file (created in SSRS 2014) in report builder of SSRS 2016 in order to save it into report manager site OR preview it, I get this error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running
the extensions specified in the config file. ---> System.Web.HttpException: 
  Maximum request length exceeded.
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, 
 HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& 
   abortProcessing)
```

Upload option on report manager site doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is due to the size of the .rdl file. My .rdl file was about 4MB, so I only needed to increase the value of maxRequestLength at httpRuntime line on web.config file and then, restart iis:

```
 httpRuntime executionTimeout = "9000" maxRequestLength="500000"
```

In this case, I set the max size to 5 MB.

Comment: is that 5mb or 488mb? Not sure if this applies but the webconfig.maxrequestLength may in KB not bytes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services 2012.  Instead of restarting IIS, I restarted SQL Server Reporting Services.  Worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue recently when I had to change a picture header. 
I found that every time you are adding image resources it keeps it in the report under Images.
Check if you have anything you can remove here:

[image: Report Data/Images]

Comment: Then you probably don't need to change default size

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify two Web.config files property under the httpruntime element. You will find under path for
1)Report Manager ***\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.12\Reporting Services\ReportManager***
2)Report Server ***\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.12\Reporting Services\ReportServer***

httpRuntime executionTimeout = "9000" **maxRequestLength="500000"**

Edit above line with bold text (as explained by ##sqluser)

Answer (score 0):

Error:“SQL Reporting Services Error- Maximum request length exceeded”

It’s an easy fix though.  You’ve got to adjust the web.config for the web app, which in the case of reporting server, is usually somewhere like this:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\Reporting Services\ReportServer
Find the web.config file for your reporting services instance, open it up, and track down the line that looks something like this

```
executionTimeout = “9000” />
```

Now just add a max request length attribute in there to fix the problem, adjust your size as needed.  This is 5meg.

```
executionTimeout = “9000” maxRequestLength=”500000″ />
```

And now you’ll need to restart IIS.  start->run->”iisreset”

https://www.isolutionspartners.com/2011/09/16/sql-reporting-services-error-maximum-request-length-exceeded/